# VBA: Execute .bat file, hide the command prompt and continue code when .bat has completed

Tags: vba, excel, batch-file

I have this piece of VBA which runs a .bat file and waits for it to complete before closing it and moving to "do stuff":

```
Sub RunFWScript()

Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1

CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run ("cmd /c pushd FilePath & filename.bat"), windowStyle, waitOnReturn

'do stuff

End Sub
```

If I replace "windowStyle, waitOnReturn" with "vbhide", I have a macro which runs the .bat file without showing the user the command prompt screen, however it immediately moves to "do stuff", not waiting the .bat to finish.

Ideally I'd like the command prompt to be hidden AND to wait on the .bat before moving to the next part of my VBA. My problem is that when I try to combine these two, i.e. go with ", vbHide, windowStyle, waitOnReturn", I get an error

"Run-time error '450':
Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment."
 Is there a way of getting these 3 commands in without error?

Comment: I haven't tested the code but it seems that placement of the parentheses of the `Run` method are incorrect.

Comment: Perhaps `"cmd /c ""pushd FilePath & filename.bat"""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, try changing the windowStyle to 0

```
Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 0
```

This will make the window invisible.